# YouTube Data API - Connecting to a Brand Account

Tags: youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to upload a video to a YouTube Brand Account but i am finding it hard. I can sign in perfectly fine with the Original Google Account and do API calls to the associated original YouTube Channel but i can't seem to gain access the Brand one.

Current Workflow:

1. Clicking button to "Connect with Google" using OAuth2 then choosing Google Account and then a YouTube Channel
2. Works fine if the YouTube channel is the original one (Not a Brand Account)
3. Do some stuff with API calls

If in step 2 i choose the Brand Account i get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eMJu.png)

Notes:

- I am trying to do all this using ASP.NET Framework MVC
- I am using a regular Google Account which is not a YouTube Partner and therefore do not have access to a Content Owner ID
- Google App is in its testing phase with the Google Account and Brand Account emails added to the test users

Question: Am i missing something? I think i have gone through all the past threads talking about Brand accounts and the various problems associated with them

Answer (score 1):

If you were invited to manage someone else's Brand Account (via channel permissions) then you will **not** be able to use the YouTube APIs.

> People you’ve invited to manage your channel can manage your channel directly on YouTube and in YouTube Studio on both computer and mobile. They can’t manage via YouTube APIs.
>
> Source: [Migrate from Brand Account user access to channel permissions](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en&ref_topic=9267586&sjid=3861685112624673855-NA#zippy=%2Cchannel-permissions-brand-account-delegation-limitations)

Regarding the error you received, it appears that the administrator of the Google account you're using has enforced certain policies that restrict or block the ability to sign in using a Google account.

> If you get an error that says “400 admin_policy_enforced” it means the administrator of your account doesn’t allow Sign in with Google. This can happen when you use an account from work or another organization. Sometimes only specific apps are blocked.
>
> **What can you do about this error?**
> If you believe you should have access to the app, reach out to your organization’s Google Workspace administrator.
>
> Source: [Troubleshoot Sign in with Google - 400 admin_policy_enforced](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12917337?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadmin-policy-enforced)